# Elliptic Envelope outlier detection

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, outliers

I want to catch outliers in the 16 x 224 array by using the Elliptic Envelope from sklearn. The problem is that when I predict the array, it gives me different dimension:

```
ell = EllipticEnvelope()
ell.fit(c)
b = ell.predict(c)
```

C is 16 x 224 as I said before, and the "b" is size 16 x 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the expected behavior.

Quoting the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.covariance.EllipticEnvelope.html#sklearn.covariance.EllipticEnvelope.predict), `predict` method returns:

> is_outliers : array, shape = (n_samples, ), dtype = bool
>
> For each observation, tells whether or not it should be considered as
>   an outlier according to the fitted model.

Note that the goal of outlier detection is to identify **samples** (rows) that are potential outliers.